# Django_tables2: Dynamically hiding columns based on the request

Tags: python, django

I have a table that's based on a model that has several fields. I also have two `TemplateColumn`s, one for editing the specific entity and another for deleting it. Here is my code:

```
class EntitetTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='azuriranje/izmena.html',
                            orderable=False, visible=False)
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='azuriranje/brisanje.html',
                            orderable=False, visible=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue', }

class TipPredmetaTable(EntitetTable):
    class Meta(EntitetTable.Meta):
        model = models.TipPredmeta
```

Now, I have a user hierarchy in my system and only users that are bookkeepers can edit and delete the data. That being said, I tried to implement a check in my view to hide the two `TemplateColumn`s:

```
@login_required
def tippredmeta(request):
    try:
        korisnik = request.user.radnik
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")
    queryset = TipPredmeta.objects.all()
    table = TipPredmetaTable(queryset)
    if korisnik.is_kustos:
        table.edit.visible = True
        table.delete.visible = True
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render_to_response('azuriranje/tabelaPrikaz.html', {'table': table, },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, I get the following exception on the `table.edit.visible = True` line:

```
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value: 'TipPredmetaTable' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

Now, here are the things I've tried:
- First I thought about using fields and exclude, but I couldn't alter that dynamically.
- Then I thought about placing all of this into the `__init__` method, effectively making edit and delete attributes of my EntitetTabel (the idea was to solve the error) but while the error was gone, so were my TemplateColumns. I tried displaying them via fields, but that didn't help. My guess is that the superclass, the tables.Table, doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `exclude` attribute of the `tables.Table` for excluding unwanted fields. It also works after creating the table instance. So in your case, you can do something like this.

First leave your columns visible (i removed the `visible=False`):

```
class EntitetTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='azuriranje/izmena.html',
                                 orderable=False)
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='azuriranje/brisanje.html',
                                 orderable=False)
```

Then based on your condition, you can exclude the edit and delete fields:

```
table = TipPredmetaTable(queryset)
if not korisnik.is_kustos:
    table.exclude = ('edit', 'delete',)
```

Comment: Damn it, I was sure I did that. It works! I'm using pycharm so I'm relying too much on his auto-complete, and when I couldn't find tabel.exclude, I thought the next (not so logical) step would be to go for tabel.Meta.exclude, which, of course, only affects the object at creation time. Thanks.